# Is there a reason I can't write to, and later read from the same csv file using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to write some averages to a csv file, then later use pandas to extract that data and create a plot from it. However, I keep getting errors when the file is read. Here's some code:

```
f = open('data.csv', 'w', newline='')
writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')
writer.writerow(['size', 'average'])

# Stuff happens

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep='\t', header=0)
```

throws the errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 38, in <module>
    data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep='\t', header=0)
  File "(file path)", line 676, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "(file path)", line 448, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
  File "(file path)", line 880, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "(file path)", line 1114, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "(file path)", line 1891, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 532, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

Comment: did you close the file when "stuff happens"?

Comment: @Simon Thanks, that did the trick. Will you post the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to close file. Use `with` to avoid this kind of problems. It will close file after `with` block.

```
with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')
    #DO STUFF WHICH USING f INSIDE THIS BLOCK
# Some pretty jobs..
# f isn't open here.
```